# Cannot access data of deserialized json

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, post

I'm using ajax to send data to my controller, here's how I do it

```
var formData = JSON.stringify( $('#SubmitForm').serializeArray() );
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {formData},
  url: '{{route("fileController.sendFiles")}}',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Here's the route

```
Route::post('/sendFiles', ['uses' => 'FileController@sendFiles'])->name('fileController.sendFiles');
```

And the controller

```
public function sendFiles(Request $request)
{
  //$data = json_decode($request->input('formData'), true);
  //return $request->input('allFiles');
  $data = json_decode($request->input('formData'), true);
  return $data['allFiles'];
}
```

However, I get this error

```
"message": "Undefined index: allFiles"
```

When I check the contents of $request, I can see that allFiles array is clearly there, but how do I access it?
P.S. I've tried changing the second param when decoding to false, there's no difference.

[$request data array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7IxA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all your request data is simple array of objects. So you cannot index it with "allFiles".
- Second since we have multiple objects with attribute name="allFiles[]", what you can do is filter those objects and return the values of it. *(I don't know how are you going to use it, but this is how the code looks)*

```php
public function sendFiles(Request $request)
{
  //$data = json_decode($request->input('formData'), true);
  //return $request->input('allFiles');
  $data = json_decode($request->input('formData'), true);
  //filter all allFiles object
  $allFiles = array_filter($data, function($obj){ 
             if(isset($obj->name)){
                return $obj->name=="allFiles[]";
             }
             return false;
           });
  //get values for all the filtered objects
  $allFilesValues = array_map(function($obj){ return $obj->value; }, $allFiles);
  return $data['allFiles'];
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It gives me a different error now, "array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members" but I will figure it out, I understood what you said now and see why it didn't work, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I passed the parameters to array_map in wrong orders. Have edited it now. Thanks.